# Troubleshooting GitHub Secrets: "Invalid Subscription or Tenant Level Error"

Tags: azure, github, automation, github-actions, azure-cli

I am trying to create a GitHub workflow and encountering an error when attempting to store secrets using the following command. It indicates either an invalid subscription or an invalid tenant level. Can someone please help me with this?

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name "myApp" --role contributor \
         --scopes /subscriptions/{subscription-      id}/resourceGroups/cloudresume/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/GetResumeCounter2410 \
         --sdk-auth
```

I was expecting to get:

```
{
    "clientId": "<GUID>",
    "clientSecret": "<GUID>",
    "subscriptionId": "<GUID>",
    "tenantId": "<GUID>",
    (...)
}
```

However, I get an error like this:

> (MissingSubscription) The request did not have a subscription or a valid tenant level resource provider.
> Code: MissingSubscription
> Message: The request did not have a subscription or a valid tenant level resource provider.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "The request did not have a subscription or a valid tenant level resource provider" indicates that the subscription ID specified is invalid or the tenant ID is incorrect.

You can use the command `az account list` to list the available subscriptions and ensure that you are using the correct subscription ID.

[image]

If you are using variables, you can use the Bash `echo` command to see the value being passed to the reference command. You can also use `az account set` to change your subscription.

Correct command-

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name "YourApp" --role contributor \
--scopes /subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<YourRGName>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{YourWebAppName} \
--sdk-auth
```

[image]

References:

- [Tutorial: Use GitHub Actions to deploy to App Service and connect to a database - Configure the GitHub secret for authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-sql-asp-github-actions#configure-the-github-secret-for-authentication)
- [Integrating with GitHub Actions - Step 2: Set up secrets in GitHub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/cicd-github-actions#step-2-set-up-secrets-in-github)

Comment: did as you asked still getting the same error